# Is it possible to mask out unsharp areas of footage with After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, post-production, alpha

Is there any existing filter/effect, that will **automatically** mask out the unsharp area of my footage?

Let's say I have an object in focus and a lot of depth of field. How do I show only my sharp object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know from 3d packages **depth information** can be represented by a 2d [Depth Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_map):

[image]

In therory it's possible to **detect the defocused area** of an image via **depth estimation methods** and **generating a depth map** using this information. The algorithm splits up the image by finding all relevant edges, analizes the gradient values and compare these areas with each other. *I doubt that this is accurate enough for every shot, but could work in some cases.* One of the latest papers, you can find here:  http://www.sjzhuo.net/defocusEstimation/

AFAIK there is only one available plugin for After Effects at the moment: http://www.yuvsoft.com/stereo-3d-technologies/automatic-depth-estimation/, but since this process is becoming increasingly important for **stereoscopic workflows**, it's a matter of time when more tools will become available.

Comment: thanks a lot man! Really interesting topic. I will give the plugin a shot and let you know if it worked for me:) thanks @poor

Comment: @SlimMarten You're welcome! Ok, great - keep me posted!